# Real time updates withing ActionListener event

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm trying to run a method within an ActionListener event that updates the imageIcon multiple times. this of course does not work. It simply shows the final imageIcon when it's done.

```
        bottomPanel.startBTN.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                gameArea.runGame();
            }
        });
```

the "runGame" method looks something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    wait 1 second;
    do something;
}
```

Comment: Swing is single threaded AND not thread safe.  This means you `for-loop` is blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing it from updating the UI.  Start with [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for some background and then [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for the simplest mechanism for solving the issue - in a way which does not violate the unsafe threading rules the API ;)

Comment: What's important to remember here is: 1. The `ActionListener` is executed within the context of the EDT; 2. Swing is single threaded, so blocking the EDT will stop it from responding to repaint requests or other events until it's unblocked; 3. Swing is NOT thread safe, so you must ensure that updates to the UI (or a state the UI relies on) is done from within the context of the EDT; 4. Swing `Timer` will do this for you (wait off the EDT and the trigger updates that occur within the EDT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to do some "background" work within swing, then I'd suggest using a [swingworker](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/).
A SwingWorker would look something similar to this:

```
public static void gameRun(){
    SwingWorker<Void, Image> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Image>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            for(int x = 0; x < myImages.length; x++) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                Image icon = ImageIO.read(myImages[x]);
                publish(icon);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<Image> icon) {
            myLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(icon.get(icon.size()-1)));
        }
    };
    worker.execute();
}
```

Edit: I've updated the answer with using the publish method to update the GUI.

Comment: No you should not be setting the Icon in the doInBackground() method. See my comment on Omore's answer.

Comment: Seems he deleted it. Could you re-post the information you provided?

Comment: Swing components need to be updated on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. You should NOT be setting the Icon in the doInBackground(...) method. Instead you should "publish" the Icon to be updated on the JLabel. Read the Swing tutorial on [Tasks That Have Interim Results}(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html) for more information and a working example. Also read the section on the `Event Dispatch Thread`

Comment: Great read - thanks. If you wouldn't mind glancing at my code that I edited above, I'd appreciate that.

Comment: Simpler to use a Swing `Timer` - personally, `SwingWorker` is unnecessarily heavy handed for something so simple.  Since `SwingWorker` introduces an additional overhead with it's processing step, it's also increasing the time between delays which may become unreasonable

Comment: Code looks reasonable. My comment was designed to clarify the usage of a SwingWorker, for future reference. The doInBackground() method is for executing a long running task, like do database access, so you don't block the EDT and prevent the GUI from being responsive. But because Swing components need to be updated on the EDT, it also provide an API (ie, the publish() method) which allows you to easily update Swing components. I also agree with the above comment above, A `Swing Timer` is much simpler

Comment: @omoshiroiii I was able to adapt your code to fit in my program, but nothing inside the "doInBackground()"  part actually runs. is there something I'm supposed to do to get it to execute?

Comment: Yes I left out the execute() method, so doInBackground() was not getting invoked - now try.

Comment: No problem, be sure to up-vote the comments above for improving the answer - which you should mark as the accepted solution by the way ;-).